# Parsing json files

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, twitter

Below is the code for visual analysis of a set of tweets obtained in a .json file. Upon interpreting , an error is shown at the map() function. Any way to fix it?

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


tweets_data_path = 'import_requests.txt'

tweets_data = []
tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, "r")

for line in tweets_file:
   try:
    tweet = json.loads(line)
    tweets_data.append(tweet)
   except:
      continue

print(len(tweets_data))

tweets = pd.DataFrame()

tweets['text'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['text'], tweets_data)
```

These are the lines leading up to the 'ValueError' message I am getting for the above code :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "tweet_len.py", line 21, in 
>            tweets['text'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['text'], tweets_data)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py",         line 1887, in **setitem**
>          self._set_item(key, value)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1966, in _set_item
>           self._ensure_valid_index(value)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line   1943, in _ensure_valid_index
>              raise ValueError('Cannot set a frame with no defined index '
>           ValueError: Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a value   that cannot be converted to a Series

I am using Python3.

EDIT : Below is a sample of the twitter data collected ( .json format).

```
{
    "created_at": "Sat Mar 05 05:47:23 +0000 2016",
    "id": 705993088574033920,
    "id_str": "705993088574033920",
    "text": "Tumi Inc. civil war: Staff manning US ceasefire hotline 'can't speak Arabic' #fakeheadlinebot #learntocode #makeatwitterbot #javascript",
    "source": "\u003ca href=\"http://javascriptiseasy.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eJavaScript is Easy\u003c/a\u003e",
    "truncated": false,
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "user": {
        "id": 4382400263,
        "id_str": "4382400263",
        "name": "JavaScript is Easy",
        "screen_name": "javascriptisez",
        "location": "Your Console",
        "url": "http://javascriptiseasy.com",
        "description": "Get learning!",
        "protected": false,
        "verified": false,
        "followers_count": 167,
        "friends_count": 68,
        "listed_count": 212,
        "favourites_count": 11,
        "statuses_count": 55501,
        "created_at": "Sat Dec 05 11:18:00 +0000 2015",
        "utc_offset": null,
        "time_zone": null,
        "geo_enabled": false,
        "lang": "en",
        "contributors_enabled": false,
        "is_translator": false,
        "profile_background_color": "000000",
        "profile_background_image_url": "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png",
        "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png",
        "profile_background_tile": false,
        "profile_link_color": "FFCC4D",
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "000000",
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "000000",
        "profile_text_color": "000000",
        "profile_use_background_image": false,
        "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/673099606348070912/xNxp4zOt_normal.jpg",
        "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/673099606348070912/xNxp4zOt_normal.jpg",
        "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/4382400263/1449314370",
        "default_profile": false,
        "default_profile_image": false,
        "following": null,
        "follow_request_sent": null,
        "notifications": null
    },
    "geo": null,
    "coordinates": null,
    "place": null,
    "contributors": null,
    "is_quote_status": false,
    "retweet_count": 0,
    "favorite_count": 0,
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [{
            "text": "fakeheadlinebot",
            "indices": [77, 93]
        }, {
            "text": "learntocode",
            "indices": [94, 106]
        }, {
            "text": "makeatwitterbot",
            "indices": [107, 123]
        }, {
            "text": "javascript",
            "indices": [124, 135]
        }],
        "urls": [],
        "user_mentions": [],
        "symbols": []
    },
    "favorited": false,
    "retweeted": false,
    "filter_level": "low",
    "lang": "en",
    "timestamp_ms": "1457156843690"
}
```

Comment: Can you add sample of `json` file?

Comment: Thank you. But this `json` is not valid. Please check it [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`read_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('file.json')
print df.head()
```

```
                       contributors  coordinates          created_at entities  \
contributors_enabled            NaN          NaN 2016-03-05 05:47:23      NaN   
created_at                      NaN          NaN 2016-03-05 05:47:23      NaN   
default_profile                 NaN          NaN 2016-03-05 05:47:23      NaN   
default_profile_image           NaN          NaN 2016-03-05 05:47:23      NaN   
description                     NaN          NaN 2016-03-05 05:47:23      NaN   

                       favorite_count favorited filter_level  geo  \
contributors_enabled                0     False          low  NaN   
created_at                          0     False          low  NaN   
default_profile                     0     False          low  NaN   
default_profile_image               0     False          low  NaN   
description                         0     False          low  NaN   

                                       id              id_str  \
contributors_enabled   705993088574033920  705993088574033920   
created_at             705993088574033920  705993088574033920   
default_profile        705993088574033920  705993088574033920   
default_profile_image  705993088574033920  705993088574033920   
description            705993088574033920  705993088574033920   

                                    ...                is_quote_status  lang  \
contributors_enabled                ...                          False    en   
created_at                          ...                          False    en   
default_profile                     ...                          False    en   
default_profile_image               ...                          False    en   
description                         ...                          False    en   

                       place  retweet_count  retweeted  \
contributors_enabled     NaN              0      False   
created_at               NaN              0      False   
default_profile          NaN              0      False   
default_profile_image    NaN              0      False   
description              NaN              0      False   

                                                                  source  \
contributors_enabled   <a href="http://javascriptiseasy.com" rel="nof...   
created_at             <a href="http://javascriptiseasy.com" rel="nof...   
default_profile        <a href="http://javascriptiseasy.com" rel="nof...   
default_profile_image  <a href="http://javascriptiseasy.com" rel="nof...   
description            <a href="http://javascriptiseasy.com" rel="nof...   

                                                                    text  \
contributors_enabled   Tumi Inc. civil war: Staff manning US ceasefir...   
created_at             Tumi Inc. civil war: Staff manning US ceasefir...   
default_profile        Tumi Inc. civil war: Staff manning US ceasefir...   
default_profile_image  Tumi Inc. civil war: Staff manning US ceasefir...   
description            Tumi Inc. civil war: Staff manning US ceasefir...   

                                 timestamp_ms  truncated  \
contributors_enabled  2016-03-05 05:47:23.690      False   
created_at            2016-03-05 05:47:23.690      False   
default_profile       2016-03-05 05:47:23.690      False   
default_profile_image 2016-03-05 05:47:23.690      False   
description           2016-03-05 05:47:23.690      False   

                                                 user  
contributors_enabled                            False  
created_at             Sat Dec 05 11:18:00 +0000 2015  
default_profile                                 False  
default_profile_image                           False  
description                             Get learning!  

[5 rows x 25 columns]
```

Comment: I am getting a 'ValueError' error message upong running the above snippet.

Comment: Funny that I am still getting the same error - ValueError:Trailing Data error message.

Comment: Hmmm, is valid original `json`? If yes, is posible share this `file`?

Comment: Here is the link to the json file - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1p05OszaBkXaXFBMG40MzljajA/view

Comment: Does it have anything to do with the version of Python?

Comment: I cannot download `file`, I send you `request`. This sample work for you? I dont know if `version` is important, so I want check it.

Comment: I have emailed the file.

Comment: Thank you. So `python.json` is invalid - `jsonlint.com` says `Error: Parse error on line 83:`. So there is problem. I get error `ValueError: Trailing data` in `read_json`

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to make my .json file valid, since I am using stream API to fetch tweets and arbitrarily stop fetching?

Comment: Hard question. Maybe try [twython](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython) for parsing json from twitter API.

Comment: Thank you for accepting. Now you can upvote answer too - click to small triangle above `0` above `accepting` mark.