# Parsing json file using Python3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, twitter

I have generated a .json file using Twitter's stream API. As a result, my .json file has multiple tweets encompassed as disconnected json objects. Upon validating using 'jsonlint' I keep getting an EOF error. Is there any possible work around this issue. My eventual aim is to visually analyze Twitter trends on the basis of keywords and hashtags. Following is my code :

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


tweets_data_path = 'import_requests.txt'

tweets_data = []
tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, "r")

for line in tweets_file:
  try:
    tweet = json.loads(line)
    tweets_data.append(tweet)
  except:
    continue

print(len(tweets_data))

tweets = pd.DataFrame()

tweets['text'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['text'], tweets_data)
```

Comment: Iterate over the lines, load each line using `json.loads`

Comment: The problem is when I use the map() function on my variable.

Comment: What do you mean? You should show code.

Comment: Yes sure, here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35811472/parsing-json-files

Comment: I don't get it,  what is the difference to the question you've linked?

Comment: Upon interpreting the code in the link, I get the error as mentioned (in the link). Is there any work around to that error (ValueError)? I posted this as a different question because I think it has something to do with the invalid json format.

Comment: @AbhijeetMohanty: you have an answer to the other question - which you have accepted. What more do you require? As mentioned in another comment, iterate over the file treating each line as a separate JSON object - if that is the format of the file. The JSON object shown in the other question parses fine with `json.loads()`. What is your question?

Comment: Your code and your JSON please! If possible reduce it to the minimun required to see the problem.

Comment: @mhawke It parses fine when there is only a single .json object (single tweet in this context).In fact, everything runs okay.But I keep getting an error at my map() function. That is my question, how do I solve the error I keep getting at my map() function?

Comment: @Klaus D Above is my python script. I keep getting ValueError at map().

Comment: @AbhijeetMohanty: Where is the JSON that is causing the problem? Show us the input that causes the problem.

Comment: This is the link to the .json file -https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1p05OszaBkXaXFBMG40MzljajA/view

Comment: @AbhijeetMohanty: stop posting off-site and cross-site references to the data, error messages, and questions. Please take the time to put your question together in a coherent way. It makes it _much_ easier to provide you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally cobbled together all of the bits and pieces regarding this question..... and find that it all works as expected. At least there is no exception being raised during `map()`. The `json` file parses OK.

Using pandas-0.16.2 on both Python 2 and 3.

The one thing that I noticed with Python 3 is that `map()` returns a `map` object, not a fully rendered list. So the data frame looks like this:

```
                              text
0   <map object at 0x7fd3a6a94f60>
1   <map object at 0x7fd3a6a94f60>
2   <map object at 0x7fd3a6a94f60>
....
```

Maybe that is the problem for you or your version of pandas.

You can fix that by using a list comprehension:

```
tweets['text'] = [tweet['text'] for tweet in tweets_data]
```

or by wrapping `map()` with `list()`:

```
tweets['text'] = list(map(lambda tweet: tweet['text'], tweets_data))
```

Then you should get this:

```
>>> tweets
                                                 text
0   Tumi Inc. civil war: Staff manning US ceasefir...
1   #bigdata #SaaS RT CStoreNews_: (Cheat Sheet) D...
2   #bigdata #SaaS RT priyaank: 24 #DataScience, #...
3   #python dropbox_tools 1.2: A collection of com...
....
```